# Windows 10: "open with" only shows "Search the store" and "Choose another app"

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-association

When I right-click on a .pde file and select "Open with ->" it only shows  "Search the store" and "Choose another app".  It doesn't show the app it's registered to open with (Processing) or the app I've repeatedly selected as an alternative (Notepad).

But it does list Processing and Notepad under "Choose another app" and then "Other options".

Not sure why it isn't populating the "Open with ->" dialog.  For all other file types on my system "Open with ->" is populated correctly.

The "OpenWithList" comes from this location in the registry, and it includes Processing and Notepad:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.pde\OpenWithList.

I tried an app suggested here at superuser ("Default Programs Editor").  It has "Change 'Open with' programs", but Processing and Notepad both show up there.  I even tried removing them, re-adding them, and rebooting.